# Xamarin.Forms: How to have a Pie Chart using data from the Database?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm creating a Xamarin.Forms Portable Application wherein I was able to display a Pie Chart using OxyPlot. My chart only has pre-defined items. What I want to do is to make the items from my DATABASE in Visual Studio to be displayed on the Chart and not the pre-defined items.

I have 2 projects in one Solution. The **WebFormsProject** and the **Xamarin.Forms (Portable)**

In my **WebFormsProject**, I created a **SalesController** where I used LINQ expression to get all the data in the database that I need. I also created a **SalesViewModel** there where I have declared all the Properties I have. I tried to test it in my WEB API if it does return a value or not, and IT DOES RETURN A VALUE.

In my PORTABLE project, I have a created **Sales** model that has exactly the same Properties with my **SalesViewModel** in the **WebFormsProject**. I also have a **SalesVM.cs** wherein I tried to access the records from the **WebFormsProject** by using SalesServices and RestClient.

I have tried using these codes but it didn't work. What do you think is the reason behind this?

Here are my codes:

**WebForms**

**1.)** SalesViewModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebFormsDemo.ViewModel
{
    public class SalesViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ORDER_ID { get; set; }
        public int ORDER_DETAILS_ID { get; set; }
        public int PRODUCT_ID { get; set; }
        public string PRODUCT_CODE { get; set; }
        public string NET_AMOUNT { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**2.)** SalesController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
using WebFormsDemo;
using WebFormsDemo.ViewModel;

namespace WebFormsDemo.Controllers
{
public class SalesController : ApiController
{
    private EBMSEntities db = new EBMSEntities();

    // GET: api/Sales
    public IQueryable<SalesViewModel> GetSalesViewModels()
    {
        //return db.SalesViewModels;
        var sales = from order in db.ORDERs
                    join order_detail in db.ORDER_DETAILS
                    on order.ORDER_ID equals order_detail.ORDER_ID
                    join prod in db.PRODUCTs
                    on order_detail.PRODUCT_ID equals prod.PRODUCT_ID
                    orderby order_detail.TOTAL_AMT_PER_ITEM descending
                    //group prod by prod.PRODUCT_CODE
                    group order_detail by prod.PRODUCT_CODE into od
                    select new SalesViewModel
                    {

                        PRODUCT_CODE = od.Key,
                        NET_AMOUNT = od.Sum(p => p.TOTAL_AMT_PER_ITEM).ToString(),

                    };

        return sales;


    }

    // GET: api/Sales/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(SalesViewModel))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetSalesViewModel(int id)
    {
        SalesViewModel salesViewModel = db.SalesViewModels.Find(id);
        if (salesViewModel == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(salesViewModel);
    }

    // PUT: api/Sales/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public IHttpActionResult PutSalesViewModel(int id, SalesViewModel salesViewModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (id != salesViewModel.Id)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        db.Entry(salesViewModel).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!SalesViewModelExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }

    // POST: api/Sales
    [ResponseType(typeof(SalesViewModel))]
    public IHttpActionResult PostSalesViewModel(SalesViewModel salesViewModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.SalesViewModels.Add(salesViewModel);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = salesViewModel.Id }, salesViewModel);
    }

    // DELETE: api/Sales/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(SalesViewModel))]
    public IHttpActionResult DeleteSalesViewModel(int id)
    {
        SalesViewModel salesViewModel = db.SalesViewModels.Find(id);
        if (salesViewModel == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        db.SalesViewModels.Remove(salesViewModel);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return Ok(salesViewModel);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private bool SalesViewModelExists(int id)
    {
        return db.SalesViewModels.Count(e => e.Id == id) > 0;
        }
    }
}
```

.

**XamarinFormsPortable**

**1.)** Sales.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace XamarinFormsDemo.Models
{
public class Sales
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ORDER_ID { get; set; }
    public int ORDER_DETAILS_ID { get; set; }
    public int PRODUCT_ID { get; set; }
    public string PRODUCT_CODE { get; set; }
    public double NET_AMOUNT { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**2.)** SalesVM.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OxyPlot;
using OxyPlot.Series;
using OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

using XamarinFormsDemo.Models;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using XamarinFormsDemo.Services;

namespace XamarinFormsDemo.ViewModels

{
    public class SalesVM
    {
    private List<Sales> salesmodel { get; set; }


    public List<Sales> SalesModelvm
    {
        get
        {
            return salesmodel;
        }
        set
        {
            salesmodel = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }





    public SalesVM()
    {

        InitializeDataAsync();


    }

    private async Task InitializeDataAsync()
    {
        var salesServices = new SalesServices();
        SalesModelvm = await salesServices.GetSalesAsync();

    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

    }
}
```

**3.)** SalesServices.cs

```
using Plugin.RestClient;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using XamarinFormsDemo.Models;
namespace XamarinFormsDemo.Services
{
    public class SalesServices
    {

    public async Task<List<Sales>> GetSalesAsync()
    {
        RestClient_Sales<Sales> restClient = new RestClient_Sales<Sales>();

        var salesList = await restClient.GetSalesAsync();

        return salesList;

        }

    }
}
```

**4.)** RestClient.cs

```
    public class RestClient_Sales<T>
    {

    private const string WebServiceUrl = "http://localhost:50857/api/Sales/";

    public async Task<List<T>> GetSalesAsync()
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();

        var json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(WebServiceUrl);

        var taskModels = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(json);

        return taskModels;
       }

    }
```

Comment: Your code is throwing an Exception... You need to use the debugger and fix it.

Comment: @jstreet In my SalesViewModel Sir I'm not yet sure with my codes there specifically this part.   dynamic seriesP1 = new PieSeries { StrokeThickness = 2.0, InsideLabelPosition = 0.8, AngleSpan = 360, StartAngle = 0};
        seriesP1.Slices.Add(salesVM.SalesModelvm);

        modelP1.Series.Add(seriesP1);
        this.SalesPerProductModel = modelP1;

Comment: Exactly, it is throwing an exception in this line: `seriesP1.Slices.Add(salesVM.SalesModelvm);`. The reason is that `Add` expects a `PieSlice` and you're passing a `List<Sales>`.... You need to replace that line with a `foreach` loop.

Comment: @jstreet Yes sir forgive me. That line is really a trial and error part for me. How can I do a foreach loop for that? Can you the codes I should use to replace that Sir? I know you can help me just like before.

Comment: I posted as an answer to avoid long pieces o code here in the comments section.

Comment: Sorry, I removed my post because it is not clear what the problem really is, and therefore, it is not useful to you or this community.

Comment: @jstreet but my real problem is how am I gonna display the data from my database to my Chart. Do you need to see more codes Sir? Please help me.

Comment: The problem is that the problem keeps changing...:O) Your service should return a `List<Sales>`. Now, if you can't do that because, as you say, `Sales` is not accessible.... you have to figure out your data structure and project organization on your own.... seeing more code is not going to help. You need to be able to at least break down your problems into smaller, manageable pieces, so people can help you with.

Comment: @jstreet Sir what do you mean I have to figure out my data structure? What should I do to solve my problem?

Comment: I just told you: your data service should return `List<Sales>`, and you said before _"`Sales` model is not accessible..."_. So, that's what i meant by figuring out your data structure and project organization.

Comment: @jstreet Sir this is my new question related to this. Hope you don't mind. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38889999/xamarin-forms-how-to-create-dynamic-pie-chart

Comment: @jstreet Sir here look : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38889999/xamarin-forms-how-to-create-dynamic-pie-chart

I have used an ObservableCollection now and do not use a List anymore. (Thanks for your advice) However, I do not manage to create a dynamic PieSlice out of the codes I have used in the Sales part of the application.

Comment: You have the troubleshooting skills to do it now.... it is the same scenario from the other day.... use the debugger to see where it is breaking. Also, remember we took `<ContentPage.BindingContext>` tag block out of your XAML and i see it back there again, so.... nothing new, you can do it, come on....

Comment: @jstreet Sir I did what we have done last day. I removed the <ContentPage.BindingContext> and put the chart to a StackLayout. But this time, I'm creating a dynamic PieSlice. I tried to set some breakpoint and I've found out that I was able to get a value on the var salesPerProduct part. However, I wasn't able to create a Slice nor display the Chart itself. Maybe you can take a look at the codes I post in my new question. Thanks a lot Sir.

Comment: Ok, I'll look at it and let you know if i find any problems.