# Xamarin.Forms: How to Authenticate LoginPage?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Good Day everyone. I'm creating a simple Xamarin.Forms Portable Application.

I have created a LoginPage and set it as my MainPage so whenever I run the application it will be the root page.

What I want to do is to Authenticate all the Users that will Log-In the system.
All the records of the Users are saved in my Database together with it's Username and Password. I retrieve all my data using WEB API. But this time, I haven't done it in my Login.

I don't have idea how am I going to do this. Please forgive me if I haven't tried anything yet. Hope you can help me.

These are some of my codes.

**LoginPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="XamarinFormsDemo.Views.LoginPage"
             BackgroundImage="bg3.jpg"
             Title="MainPage">




  <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center"
                 Padding="40">

    <Image Source="ebmslogo1.png"/>

    <StackLayout Padding="0,50,0,0">



      <Entry x:Name="txtUserName"
                 Placeholder="Username"
                 x:Hint="Username"
                 BackgroundColor="Black"
                 TextColor="White"/>

      <Entry x:Name="txtPassword"
             Placeholder="Password"
             IsPassword="true"
             BackgroundColor="Black"
             TextColor="White"/>

      <Button Text="LOG IN"
              FontSize="14"
             BackgroundColor="Teal"
             Clicked="NavigateButton_OnClicked"/>



    </StackLayout>

  </StackLayout>



</ContentPage>
```

**LoginPage.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace XamarinFormsDemo.Views
{
    public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
    {
        public LoginPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);

        }
        private async void NavigateButton_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new MenuPage());

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you already have authentication and authorization built into your Web API?

Comment: @NateBarbettini No Sir. I don't have it yet. Hope you can help me.

Comment: Did you set your Login Page as your root page of your application? Please, check the App class (inside app.cs in your Shared project) and make sure your root point is set to your Login Page. Good luck!

Comment: @JayceeEvangelista If you have built a web API then you can use web API authentication to authenticate your user to an actual server and in the second the step you can save all the user related details to the database with the token returned by the authentication. And use it for offline login.

Comment: @relez Sir I'm done with that. What I need is to authenticate the users that comes from my database are allowed to login the system. Where will I start?

Comment: @ParthPatel Sir I have my WEB API but not for this one. Can you please tell me how am I gonna to it and how to use web api authentication?

Comment: @JayceeEvangelista You need to implement OWin Auth for your web API. So if there is an internet connection and try to login then it will request your web API and get Authentication token in response and you can save it in your local db to provide offline login. You can follow this http://bitoftech.net/2015/01/21/asp-net-identity-2-with-asp-net-web-api-2-accounts-management/ for token implementation.

Comment: @ParthPatel will this be applicable with my situation Sir? I've created now a n API controller that allow me to get all the User information including username and password. But I don't know what to do next. When a user key in data to my username and password textbox, the system should check if that records exist in the user information retrieved  by my WEB API.

Comment: @JayceeEvangelista It will perfectly suit your situation

Comment: @ParthPatel Sir I have read the link you provided. Can I really use it in Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: @JayceeEvangelista Yes you can use it